# spark application java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory

Tags: java, apache-spark, out-of-memory

5. I'm using following run time spark configuration values

> spark-submit --executor-memory 8G 
>   --spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead 2G

but it still raise following out of memory error:

I have a pairRDD having 8362269460 lines and partition size is 128 .It raise this error when pairRDD.groupByKey.saveAsTextFile .Any clue?

update:
      I add a filter,and now data lines is 2300000000.Running in spark shell,no error.
      My cluster: 
                 19 datenode 1 namdnode

```
             Min Resources: <memory:150000, vCores:150>
             Max Resources: <memory:300000, vCores:300>
```

Thanks for your help.

> ```
> org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
>   at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:321)
>   at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:306)
>   at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:51)
>   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
>   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
>   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
>   at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:132)
>   at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineValuesByKey(Aggregator.scala:60)
>   at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.HashShuffleReader.read(HashShuffleReader.scala:89)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:90)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
>   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException:  Direct buffer memory
>   at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:234)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
>   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
>   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
>   ... 1 more
> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
>   at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:658)
>   at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
>   at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:306)
>   at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.newUnpooledChunk(PoolArena.java:651)
>   at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocateHuge(PoolArena.java:237)
>   at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:215)
>   at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.reallocate(PoolArena.java:358)
>   at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.capacity(PooledByteBuf.java:121)
>   at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.ensureWritable(AbstractByteBuf.java:251)
>   at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:849)
>   at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:841)
>   at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:831)
>   at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder$1.cumulate(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:92)
>   at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:228)
>   ... 10 more
> )
> ```

I'd like to know how to correctly configure Direct Memory size.
Best regards

Comment: please format your question properly and give some context to it

Comment: @ssyue -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize

Comment: @manRo sorry,english is my weakness.

Comment: @Marek-A- thanks,but how to set it on spark application?

Comment: Post the spark-defaults.conf file, it will provide context to the question, and use Garbage collection correctly. G1GC should be used.

Comment: @sparkDabbler thanks,G1GC not work,any else solution?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know any details about spark app, but i find the memory configuration [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#memory-management)
you need to set `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` similar as any else JVM mem. setting (over -XX:)
try to use `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions`

If you are using `spark-submit` you can use:

```
./bin/spark-submit --name "My app" ...
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m" myApp.jar
```

Comment: but this memory error rather means that your application has any memory issue, e.g you read whole stream content to memory buffer

Comment: @ravindra I have a pairRDD  having 8362269460 lines (eg:(867196025682574,(A10000456C2DA1,0.0010017530678687703))) and partition size is 128 .It raise this error when pairRDD.groupByKey.saveAsTextFile

Comment: As suggested before, and also by different folks here, please post the code and the spark-defaults.conf file. Your comments do not provide enough context to the problem

Comment: @ssyue - the value you use in parameter needs to correspond with amount data you processing within direct memory, it may still raise same issue if the data are to huge. Please post your code, solution will be in change of processing algorithm.